# I'm stuck on the loading screen of GTA V story mode

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I tried uninstalling then reinstalling it.
I tried deleting the rockstar games folder in (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles\SC_NUMBER).
I tried to find Social Club folder in C:\ProgramData but was unable to find it
What should i do?
And I've purchased the game from epic store.

Comment: Welcome to gaming stackexchange! Could you elaborate on 'stuck'. How long have you been waiting? What do you see? Perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: I have waited for about 5-10 mins.

Comment: Today I pasted my old save file which i had deleted in the path mentioned above. Then tried to launch online session instead and it worked. Then i got to story mode and it worked to.

Comment: Now i tried to close and directly run the story mode and it worked well.So now i think it was save file error only.

Comment: Should i delete this question or keep it posted.

Comment: You could answer your own question, which is perfectly fine. Try to explain in as much detail as possible so it is usable by future viewers.